# How to get mean of rows selected with another column's values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to get calculate the mean for Score 1 only if column `Dates` is equal to `Oct-16`:

[image]

What I originally tried was:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import os

 dataFrame = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

 for date in dataFrame["Dates"]:
    if date == "Oct-16":
        print(date)##Just checking
        print(dataFrame["Score 1"].mean())
```

But my results are the mean for the whole column `Score 1`

Another thing I tried was manually telling it which indices to calculate the mean for:

```
dataFrame["Score 1"].iloc[0:2].mean()
```

But ideally I would like to find a way to do it if `Dates == "Oct-16"`.

Comment: you want `df.loc[df['Dates'] == 'Oct-16', 'Score 1'].mean()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterating through the rows doesn't take advantage of Pandas' strengths.  If you want to do something with a column based on values of another column, you can use [`.loc[]`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
dataFrame.loc[dataFrame['Dates'] == 'Oct-16', 'Score 1']
```

The first part of `.loc[]` selects the rows you want, using your specified criteria (`dataFrame['Dates'] == 'Oct-16'`).  The second part specifies the column you want (`Score 1`).  Then if you want to get the mean, you can just put `.mean()` on the end:

```
dataFrame.loc[dataFrame['Dates'] == 'Oct-16', 'Score 1'].mean()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It appears to be solving the issue I had.

Answer (score 2):

How about the mean for all dates

```
dataframe.groupby('Dates').['Score 1'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

dataFrame = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

dates = dataFrame["Dates"]
score1s = dataFrame["Score 1"]
result = []

for i in range(0,len(dates)):
    if dates[i] == "Oct-16":
        result.append(score1s[i])

print(result.mean())
```