# Calculating mean from excel column for specific timeframe

Tags: python, excel

I'm relatively new to Python and I encountered an issue I can't seem to solve. I have imported an excel sheet in Python - it's full of Timestamps and corresponding glucose values.

I got my code to display timestamp-glucose pairs for a specific timeframe with the purpose of being able to analyze separate chunks from the data. So now I can just specify that I only want the data from the afternoon or the morning or X day before I hit 'Run'.

I want to run some basic calculations. I want to be able to enter the time-range and then get average glucose ONLY for the specified time period, but I'm struggling. I get the average glucose of the whole data by simply having this line:

```
print(df['Historic Glucose mmol/L'].mean())
```

But when it comes to getting averages for the specified time period I'm not sure how to do it. I looked into questions on here but couldn't find similar ones. Additionally, I have looked at possible numpy functions but I don't think they would help. If anyone has any suggestions I'd be grateful. Below is a chunk of code that gets me the specified timeframes:

```
dataSubSection = df
sDate = datetime(2019,11,21,17,17,00)
eDate = datetime(2019,11,22,00,00,0)
start_date = sDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
end_date = eDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: You appear to be using Pandas, is that correct? Have you seen https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html and [Select DataFrame rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates) ?

Comment: @AMC Thank you for this, I found some useful information in your second link and managed to solve the issue!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  the OP has resolved the issue, as stated in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

What is the package that you are using to import the dataset?

Given the information provided, this is how I would approach it

I would use pandas and do `pandas.read_excel()` 
(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

and once the dataset is in pandas, I would do something like this to calculate the mean on specific rows ([How to get mean of rows selected with another column's values in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40074739/how-to-get-mean-of-rows-selected-with-another-columns-values-in-pandas))

If your dataset is large or you anticipate it to get larger with time, I think it would be worth the effort to start looking into pyspark.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I am indeed using pandas. I managed to solve the problem with the upper comment but I ended up looking into pyspark and I think it'll come in handy with the rest of my work so thank you for pointing is out to me.